# Python Excel column array variable

Tags: python, arrays, excel

I have an excel sheet which looks like

```
Name           email                desc           date
name1          email1               desc1          date1
name2          email2               desc2          date2
name3          email3               desc3          date3
```

Im looping through and inserting the data into an array and printing information on each row

```
import xlrd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = xlrd.open_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
row_count = sheet.nrows
curr_row = 0
row_array = []
while curr_row < row_count:
  row = sheet.row(curr_row)
  row_array += row
  curr_row +=1
  print row_array
```

This adds everything into one array.

I want to be able to call

```
row_array[1][2] and desc1 comes up or 
row_array[3][0] and name 3 comes up.
```

How can i achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx', read_only=True)
>>> ws = wb.active
>>> data = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in ws.rows]
>>> data[1][2]
'desc1'
>>> data[3][0]
'name3'
```

The `data` list may be a little obscure, unrolling the code would give:

```
data = []
for i, row in enumerate(ws.rows):
    data.append([])
    for cell in row:
        data[i].append(cell.value)
```

Comment: Little reminder: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, if the answer is good for you :)